# How do I remove the 'Applet Started' message in the status bar of Firefox/Chrome on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, firefox, google-chrome, ubuntu, applet

This is for a kiosk application where this message is not desired. It's odd because Mac doesn't display this message in either browser -- seems to only happen on Ubuntu.

Comment: If it is a kiosk application then why is there a status bar at all? If you have control over the system where the app is used from, you can either deactivate the status bar or make the browser full screen...

Answer (score 2):

Using this [example applet](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) on Ubuntu 10, Firefox 12, I was able to reproduce the message "Applet initialized," illustrated below. It doesn't *appear* to be from an overridden `init()`, and the `super` implementation is empty; I presume it's a feature of either the plug-in or the browser itself. Oddly, the message actually *moves* from one lower corner of the browser window to the other, as the mouse cursor approaches it.

For embedded use, consider starting the applet (or hybrid application) via [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) as shown in the [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway).

[image]

Addendum: Andrew's example produces the message "Applet started."

[image]

Comment: Demonstrative screen-grab.  I am curious to see the effect of the source shown in the edit to my answer.  Could you do a screen-grab of it?  I thought those 'Nobody Here' messages would appear in the exact same spot as 'Applet initialized' - effectively wiping out the original message. But now I am not so sure..

Comment: @Andrew: I added an `appletviewer` screenshot to your answer; it looks the same in the browser, but the message is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like futzing to me, but if by 'status bar' you mean the little bar at the bottom of older browsers, try using [`Applet.showStatus("")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#showStatus%28java.lang.String%29) at the end of `init()` or `start()`.

---

Edit: Using the following command produces the expected result in `appletviwer`.

```
$ appletviewer NoMessageApplet.java
```

[image]

Code:

```
// intended only to show attributes - view in browser
// <applet code='NoMessageApplet' width=400 height=400></applet>
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NoMessageApplet extends JApplet {

    String noMessage = " Nobody Here But Us Chickens..";
    JTextArea output;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initGui();
                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initGui() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        output = new JTextArea(5,20);
        gui.add(new JScrollPane(output));

        setContentPane(gui);
        setMessage("initGui()" + noMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        setMessage("start()" + noMessage);
    }

    /** Both sets the message as the 'status' message &
    appends it to the output control */
    public void setMessage(final String message) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                output.append(message + "\n");
            }
        });
        showStatus(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are init() and/or start() located? Definitely not futzing, this is for kiosk app... it's a requirement (picture RedBox with a "Applet Started" message at the bottom of the screen -- how crappy would that be...). Thanks.

Comment: *"Where are init() and/or start() located?"*  (?!?)  Presumably the applet has **overriden** the `init()` method.  *"it's a requirement"* That doesn't save it from being futzing, it just shifts it up the line to **whoever specified it.**

Comment: Would the down-voter care to share their reason?  Eager to learn, here.

Comment: @Andrew: Not your down-voter, but the message doesn't _appear_ to be from `init()`, judging by this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway). With Firefox, it _moves away_ when you try to click it! Mark: you might try the "Applet via Java Web Start" approach, _ibid_.

Comment: @trashgod I both understand and +1 the last sentence, but am still a little too groggy to understand quite what you mean in the first parts.  I'll leave this open and muse over it.

Comment: Good morning, NSW! More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10645498/230513) after [coffee](http://science.slashdot.org/story/12/05/17/1625203/nih-study-finds-that-coffee-drinkers-have-lower-risk-of-death).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question but definitely a possible solution to your problem (Was a comment. Added as an answer as suggested by @Andrew Thompson):

If it is a kiosk application then why is there a status bar at all? 
If you have control over the system where the application is used from (or where the browser is installed), you can either deactivate the status bar in the browser or make the browser to be displayed always in full screen mode.

Most kiosk applications operate this way.

Answer (score 0):

FF13 fixed it (so does the most recent version of Chrome). Both now currently do not enable status bar's by default (they did when I made this initial post). Not quite an answer, but an *answer* that worked for me.